# Can we use the API of google maps in Unity 3D?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, unity-game-engine

I want to know, can we use all the API's of [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/) in [Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/) (not just a static map, I want to locate my position, add a lot of markers with window information, select itinerary from my position to a selected marker ...)

Have a good day and thanks ! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is yes, you can use the Google maps API with Unity as long as you adhere to the licensing agreement for the Google maps API.

However, if you're asking if there is special support in Unity for the Google maps API then the answer is no. However, there is at least one third party [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/google-maps-view-82542) that supports Google maps. You could probably use it or a different asset to get you started with integration.

Comment: The package you have mentioned in the link is deprecated.

Comment: Updated to a non-deprecated, but unfortunately not open source, asset.